# RelativeLayout inside ScrollView with a button aligned to bottom of its parent

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` structured in a "header/body/footer" style.

- In the header section I have a `TextView` showing the title of the current fragment;
- the body includes a `ScrollView` element wrapping a `RelativeLayout` which contains other elements;
- finally, the footer just has a `Button`.

Specifically, the structure is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView />                <!-- the header -->

    <ScrollView>                <!-- the body -->
        <RelativeLayout>
            <!-- other elements -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScollView>

    <Button />                  <!-- the footer -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I want the button to be always to the bottom of the main `RelativeLayout`, so I assigned the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Also, the `ScrollView` must fill all the body, so the property `android:fillViewport="true"` has been set.

**Problem**: the fact is that the button in the footer goes over the final part of the `ScrollView`, thus hiding the final elements of the `RelativeLayout` containing the body. Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting

```
android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_your_button"
```

on the ScrollView

Comment: Great! It works like a charm. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @f_ficarola Glad I could help. If it answers your question you might consider accepting the answer

Comment: Yes, I was just waiting for StackOverflow allowing me to accept your answer! ;)